# how to set transparent image background color to theme color in qml

Tags: qml, qt-quick

is it possible to set a background color to a transparent image in QML, so that the image will take the theme color as it's baclground color.

thanks...

Answer (score 3):

Put your transparent `Image` over a coloured Item (like a `Rectangle`).

You just need to set `z` property of the `Image` greater than the `Rectangle`'s one.

Comment: I tried like the following, it's not working...
`Rectangle
{
 id: rect1
 width: img.width
 height: img.height
 //color: "transparent"
 color: dropDownBox.themeColor
 //z: 0
 Image {
  id: img
  source: "abc.png"
  smooth: true  
  fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
  z: 22
 }
}`

do you find any issues on this. Thanks

Comment: "It's not working" is not a problem descirption. What's the resulting behavior?